# Print Javascript in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of making an addon for a software that basically allows you to have 'responsive' adverts, by checking the page size with javascript and then outputting the relevant ad code to the screen.

This works fine for text ad codes, however I've hit a snag when the ad code is javascript - I can't get the user-provided javascript to output to the page and be executed.

Is this possible at all?

Here is some example code:

```
<div id="admanagerresponsive">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      adUnit = document.getElementById("admanagerresponsive");
      adWidth  = adUnit.offsetWidth;

      if (adWidth >= 728) {
        <output ad code>
      }
    </script>
</div>
```

The code above will be directly in the page.

Is such a thing possible?

EDIT:

could be any advertiser's code, such as adsense. It'll be user provided, and will be standard html. However, it could contain  tags, and these will need to be rendered and outputted correctly...

Comment: What's in this `<output ad code>` part?  There's always `document.write()`, but its usage is strongly discouraged.  Perhaps you're looking for `exec()`? Show us what's in that block so we can provide a proper solution.

Comment: @Brad the edit will be of use...

Comment: Be careful what JS ads you allow: injecting 3rd party javascript code into a website opens the door for lots of dangerous exploits!

Comment: @Philipp the advert code will be entered through the scripts admincp. It's just an easier way than editing the templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to inject add html code containing `script` tags and you are award of the security problems, i suggest to use a library like jQuery that takes care about the cross browser issues with executing `<script>` tags added later.

Additionally you need to take care about various pitfalls like:
Html paring is done before script parsing, so no matter where a `</script>` appears this will immediately *end* your script.

The examples are important for the situations where you have that code as inline script inside your html page.

**Example 1:**

```
<script>
      adUnit   = document.getElementById("admanagerresponsive");
      adWidth  = adUnit.offsetWidth;if (adWidth >= 728) {
           // if you add </script> <b>this is visible as html</b> and everything below is not script anymore
      }
</script>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<script>
      adUnit   = document.getElementById("admanagerresponsive");
      adWidth  = adUnit.offsetWidth;if (adWidth >= 728) {
           var string = "<script> var test;</script>";//the same problem here everything behind the closing script tag is html and not script anymore
      }
</script>
```

So if you need to have some script to inject there you need to make the `</script>` not to be detectable by the html parser:

```
<script>
      adUnit   = document.getElementById("admanagerresponsive");
      adWidth  = adUnit.offsetWidth;if (adWidth >= 728) {
           var string = "<script> var test;</sc"+"ript>";//that way the html parser does not detect the closing script tag
      }
</script>
```

A better solution is not to use inline script at all, not only for that reason, but because you should always keep css, js and html separated.

Answer (score 0):

Break it into two ideas.  From your HTML above, just call a js function you wrote somewhere else.  Initially have that js function be an alert, to verify that works.

Once that works, you have the problem: how can I get custom js for a page?  The answer to that is hopefully that you can create and load a (one-off, custom) js file the same way you create an html file.  Or, libraries such as now.js could help.  Or, there is a script portion of your html page that you understand how to assemble to include the js.

You could even preload all your size possibilities, then have the js routine from the first paragraph pick the right routine to call,